# Do Physics Hot Network Questions help or harm the site?

Tags: discussion

There has been some small discussion in the [comments of a recent post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/can-we-do-better-at-reducing-bike-shedding#comment46921_12513/179151) about Physics SE questions appearing in the list of Hot Network Questions (HNQ). It was also brought up that Physics SE can choose to be removed from this list, but even if this is not a choice to be made, I think a discussion about the pros and cons of Physics SE in the HNQ would still be a good one to have.

From what I can tell, the good side of the HNQ is that it gets more people to view the site. If the HNQ question they have arrived at is a good question with good answers, then they will most likely learn some physics, which is awesome. Additionally, these new viewers might explore other questions on the site. So the HNQ essentially brings in more viewers and users, and helps spread physics knowledge to the community. I think everyone can agree these are positive outcomes.

On the other hand, there are instances where HNQ physics questions are not very good questions, at least by the standards of typical Physics SE posts. The question could be poorly written, or it could be about a "pop-sci" topic that many people think they know a lot about, thus garnering many poor quality answers. This is not necessarily bad for regular users and physics experts on the site (although it can be annoying sometimes), but it could be bad for new users to the site and to physics, as they will have an incorrect view of how Physics SE, or physics in general, works.

In my opinion, I think the good outweighs the bad here. Even if there are some "bad apples", I think more people coming here and learning about physics is always good. Plus, we have measures in place to mitigate the bad side. Users can vote on questions and answers, vote to close questions, and even [flag questions to be removed from the HNQ should moderators agree to remove them](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11146/179151). Of course these measures might not always be enough, but they are what we have at the moment.

What do other, regular Physics SE users think about the HNQ? What are some other pros and cons, and does the bad really outweigh the good?

Please note that this post is not intended to be a discussion on how the HNQ could be better handled on PSE. This post is just intended to be a discussion on how the HNQ affects the site in its current state, and whether it is a net good or net bad effect.

Comment: It's more con than pro for me. (my opinion)

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha Would you care to explain in an answer to this post?

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha Ah ok. Well I am not really talking about personal preferences here as to which questions an individual would want to see or not see. I am discussing more about in the context of the site as a whole. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @all: **Proposing improvements to the way the software works is not a constructive use of this thread**, which is about how the influx of traffic from HNQ affects this site and whether we're happy with the questions that are making the list right now. If you have thoughts on how the software should run, take them to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) or to [meta.se] ─ just be sure to read [the announcement on the latest batch of changes to the feature](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/325060) first, at the very least.

Comment: Is there an easy way to automatically protect HNQs so that occasional users don't disproportionately upvote the question?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero At the moment, [protecting a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question) just prevents lower-rep users from answering it, but doesn't impact voting. [Locking a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post) prevents everything including voting, but applies to everybody. There isn't a tool in the system at the moment that would lock only for lower-rep users.

Comment: @tpg2114 right... Thanks for reminding me of this.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero No, but you can help support [this proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286020/breaking-the-hnq-feedback-loop-on-bad-questions) (and other related ones in its Linked sidebar) if you think that that's something that still requires changing.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I did just that.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Disagree. Arbitrarily driving traffic to the site only increases the noise to signal. It's the same or worse as being pinned, which is why I'm here and you just wasted one minute of your life reading what I just wrote.

Comment: Currently there's, *Why are the rain clouds darker?*.... posted 13h ago from a user who already quit. - Coupled with the fact that you'd need to raise a custom flag to a moderator, instead of an actual flag for it, I don't see how that question or what would have to be manually done to it by a moderator 'helps' the site.

Comment: @Mazura It would be helpful to post your thoughts as well as any evidence that HNQ doesn't do any good for the site.

Comment: No evidence, only logic. If a Q goes on the list, it gets more attention (which is unideal when predominantly from outside the group of 'experts') then it would have otherwise. "People don't DV enough is all I'm seeing in the data." ... so all that's happening is more noise via UVs from random people on the internet. That skews the votes between all Qs into a binary list of those that have been on, and those that have *not* been on, the list.

Comment: Once in a while, somebody comes out of the woodwork and drops us a gem. Really what it does though is drive site traffic. The question is, is that a good thing? Unless you make money off of ads, traffic usually isn't a good thing. - If this was ELU the answer would be straight up no; it's all they can do to try and stem the tide of the onslaught of '1rep' Qs, which are usually benign enough to attract novice attention and end up on the list. That bumps serious questions, answered by experts, down the line. S/N fading....

Comment: @Mazura I think it would be helpful to put your comments into an answer.

Comment: There already is a useful answer but nobody is using it to do anything. Ever since the 'impact' metric came out I've been thinking of how you might 'metric' the votes on these Qs into falling in line where they should be, but I'm not a mathematician. And it'd be an inherently flawed process anyway.

Comment: @Mazura Unlike the main site, the meta site is often used for discussions. Your answer does not have to be a post that is correct or incorrect. It just needs to contribute to the discussion. Given the amount of things you have said in the comments, I think an answer putting your comments in one place would be helpful

Comment: [Can we do better at reducing bike-shedding?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12527/52988) "Personally I came to the conclusion that unless this [("All they can do is upvote"]) [HNQ] voting asymmetry is somehow fixed..." versus a comment here : "Proposing improvements to the way the software works is not a constructive use of this thread". - Same problem, same N/A solution.

Comment: @Mazura How involved are you on PhysicsSE?

Comment: Not enough that I should be contributing here. And for years I thought the criteria for a HNQ was secret, which is false. I'm pretty sure I've worn out my welcome, but I would like to see this metric: assuming, if I answered a question on DiY then that makes it a 'good question'. Now, *what's the difference in those Q's points* of the ~600 Qs I've answered that have been on, and not been on, the HNQ? I'm assuming there's a difference of about five to one or more. Of those 600 answers, none jump to my mind as being any better than the others. That metric is the 'harm' factor.

Comment: Not having read your first link until today didn't help. And now armed with the secrets of the HNQ list, IMO it's your user base that is putting them on it in the first place. Qs at DiY are unlikely to ever exceed the high teens, here that seems common place (whether they're HNQ or not?). The 'per site' adjustment needs a higher threshold because of the amount of traffic this site receives *prior to being a HNQ*. - Good or bad? Unknown, but it *will* exacerbate existing in-site problems and present them site-wide to be further exacerbated.

Answer (score 14):

I think the main effect by which the HNQ questions harm our site is completely disconnected from their quality: They drown out smaller topics, and they favour questions with non-technical answers.

Their topics are either classical/quantum mechanics at (at most) undergraduate level, questions about everyday life situations or something some pop-science publication wrote about. Additionally, the highest voted answers are usually - and understandably, given that a large share of viewers of these questions are not regular users - those most accessible (and most authoritative-sounding) to non-physicists.

Now, there's nothing inherently wrong with such questions, but it means that people who like to ask and answer questions of this type get disproportionally more upvotes than those who prefer smaller subfields or technical questions. This is *in addition* to the voting pool for these things being smaller to begin with because the fraction of regular users who are interested in them and can judge correctness there is of course also smaller for smaller subfields.

Now, I can't *prove* the following assertion, but I believe that many (not all!) experts naturally are of the second kind of users: They want to answer detailed questions about the subfield they're proficient in, not "general physics" questions. The HNQ questions therefore do us a disservice because they have the potential to attract a lot more askers whose physics knowledge is minimal, but they don't really attract (or might even deter) users competent beyond a general physics education.

From personal experience I can certainly say that I find it extremely frustrating when, thanks to HNQ, my second-highest voted answer is a one-liner on basic special relativity, while many answers I poured actual effort into don't even make a double-digit number of votes. As I said, less votes for more specialized posts are to be expected anyway, but HNQ magnifies this effect considerably.

Comment: Yeah I see that my highest voted answers are the shorter ones that ended up on HNQ, and there are times where I put so much effort into an answer and it gets very minimal attention. But does the HNQ prevent the more specific topics from being looked at? I guess really what needs to be (somehow) looked at is how "self-contained" the HNQ is. Do people who visit and interact with these questions then go move onto the rest of the site, and if so, what effect does that have? I don't think there would be a way to determine this though.

Comment: "Do people who visit and interact with these questions then go move onto the rest of the site, and if so, what effect does that have? I don't think there would be a way to determine this though" $-$ this *can* be determined, just not by us. That data isn't public, but SE does have a team of data scientists on staff to do precisely this kind of data crunching (cf. [this recent blog post](//stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/12/research-update-a-b-testing-the-new-question-form/)). Whether SE management has put HNQ high up on their priorities list, on the other hand, is a completely different matter...

Comment: This is presenting a false dichotomy though. It's not like we can choose between  having popular questions and having lots of experts. As we saw with the theoretical physics SE and PhysicsOverflow, attracting expert attention is just hard, because experts have a lot to do, and collaborators they can discuss physics with in person. None of the 50+ physicists I know at my university use Physics.SE, and I don't imagine any of them would start if I told them the HNQ was abolished.

Comment: I post answers for the enjoyment of helping others, to help clarify my own thinking, and to counter popular incorrect statements. The first two are completely independent of the HNQ, while the third benefits from it.

Comment: @knzhou I'm not saying we shouldn't have this kind of questions - I'm saying HNQ rewards them disproportionately beyond what they would get from being "popular" among the regular userbase already

Comment: @ACuriousMind But is that necessarily bad for the site overall?

Comment: I don't think HNQ are helpful but I'm not sure if they are harmful.   "drown out" is too strong for my own taste but I do regret some HNQ are disproportionately prominent: thankfully there aren't enough terrible HNQ IMO to cause serious harm to the site.  @EmilioPisanty if there a way to query the system and obtain the number of upvotes on HNQ before and after the change in policy?  i.e. is there a way to adjust your script to see if the new policy somehow reduced the prominence of HNQ (by using the proxy of counting upvotes)?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Almost but not quite. Voting data has timestamps, but in the public SEDE they're rounded down to the date (with no time) due to strong and valid privacy considerations. Given that most HNQs make the list within a day of posting, the public data would be too noisy to be useful. In any case, though, without a good control, I'm not sure what we'd learn from such a query. Obviously the bulk of the upvotes will come after the questions gets advertised, but what do we learn from that?

Comment: (Note also, regarding "to see if the new policy somehow reduced the prominence of HNQ", that this data ─ which questions made it to HNQ and when ─ only started getting logged at all when the policy changed. There are no data available of the 2013-2019 period before the policy change ─ it simply wasn't ever logged. When challenged (cf. the link in my answer), SE devs cited weak "performance" arguments to justify that, though evidently the problems were solvable.)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I was curious to see if allowing some community intervention to "delist" HNQ broadly reduced the total number of upvotes to these questions, but one would need some timing data which I gather is not available.   I have a sense that the truly terrible HNQ are "delisted" reasonably quickly and that the scale of the problem of upvoting bad questions (and associated answers) has been reduced, but this could be confirmation biais.

Comment: Well, this is why the lack of logging pre-HNQcalypse, and the decision to roll out the functional changes *without* allowing for a few months of logging on the old system, is so frustrating. There's probably a fair amount that can be gotten from the behaviour of questions that get delisted (and if you can sharpen the general question into a specific query, I can write it for you), but none of that can be compared to the pre-change status quo. gah. We complained for years pointing out that this is precisely what would happen, and got nowhere. And now we have data we can't use. Great!

Comment: @AaronStevens I think it makes the site a bit more "pop-sci" oriented (for lack of a better word) than I'd like it to be, so I see it as "harmful". I frankly just chose "harmful" because your question asked about "help or harm", This isn't such a major harm that I'd necessarily argue we'd need to stop being listed on HNQs or whatever - I just wanted to give a perspective that doesn't rely on hashing out whether or not the questions appearing there are "good" by whatever measure.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Thank you for your input

Comment: 'might even *deter* users competent beyond a general physics education' - that's bathwater I'm willing to throw out with the baby, +1.

Comment: *my second-highest voted answer is a one-liner on basic special relativity, while many answers I poured actual effort into don't even make a double-digit number of votes* Are aware that you'd not have different number of votes on the less popular topics if HNQ were not a thing though?

Answer (score 8):

Whatever our opinion, it should be based on actual data, i.e., on the full set of questions from this site that get promoted on the HNQ sidebar.

Luckily, [the update to the HNQ mechanisms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325060/updating-the-hot-network-questions-list-now-with-a-bit-more-network-and-a-litt) from March of this year *finally* (after [years of asking for it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286986/please-open-the-hot-network-questions-to-auditing-via-the-data-explorer)) allowed us to track what does and does not get on that sidebar, exposing this aspect of question history both to the question revisions list and [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54366/feedback-request-newer-timeline-question-view) as well as to the Data Explorer.

So, to that effect, a couple of months ago I wrote a SEDE query,

> [Upvotes and downvotes on HNQ questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/1097679/upvotes-and-downvotes-on-hnq-questions),

which lists this site's HNQs as well as some statistics on their scores.

So: before you make some categorical statement about things which are Good For The Site, or Bad For The Site, or The End Of Stack Exchange As We Know It, or something, go and have a look and see whether it holds up against the actual data. (Say: if your impression is negative, are you sure that this isn't just because of a "vocal minority" of bad questions that are easy to notice, and that various human biases bring to further prominence than they really should have?)

Comment: Yes I agree. I think the data is extremely important as well. Thank you

Comment: People don't DV enough is all I'm seeing in the data. But that's a problem we've had for a long while (see [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6867/25301), [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6767/25301), etc) and not particular to HNQ

Comment: @KyleKanos And the number of votes on the question does not reflect the quality of answers either.

Comment: @KyleKanos I agree that some of these don't get downvoted enough but for my part I find it eventually  mentally exhausting to constantly downvote.  It's like constantly bitching: it gets to you.

Comment: Bitching is basically all I'm here to do and I can't DV either. Votes are supposed to signal where it is in all the noise; the only currency SE has. **Votes from the list devalue that currency.** If we wanted answers and votes to be all over the place, then we should've called it Yahoo. If specific sites are for experts and enthusiasts, I expect the people voting on them to have a stake, so to speak, not just a passing interest, which is why at <125 rep, it doesn't count. However that's a trivial amount for an 11yo site...

Comment: *Top posts* divided by their age, versus *HNQ posts* divided by age, is a ratio of what, and where does that leave standard questions? The problem with that is the subjective opinion of what a 'really good question' is and whether it should have as many votes as a top Q that was never on the list. There's no control group so there's nothing to do with the data.

Comment: @Mazura Your two comments here are basically word salad. If you have *specific* metrics that you're interested in that you're having trouble fishing out of SEDE then I'm happy to help you build a query for it or to write one for you. If you have constructive criticism, then I'm happy to hear it, but if the only thing you're going to post is unconstructive negativity - maybe that's a thing on Home Improvement, but it's not appropriate or constructive here.

Comment: I prefer the term *stone soup* (admittedly, I've no idea what I'm talking about - and you've admitted not knowing what to do with the data either). "without a good control, I'm not sure what we'd learn from such a query." - "We complained for years pointing out that this is precisely what would happen, and got nowhere. And now we have data we can't use." - I have an extremely specific metric I'd like to know (that we can't, and it's the only one that matters) : what puts a Q on the list? Why would that knowledge need to be kept hidden if the list was a good thing?

Comment: There is a 'thing' at Home Improvement that's worth mentioning. Basically you get one or two upvotes on answers (or none, which is how I got *tenacious*) which signals to the community that *this checks out, move along*. But if it goes to the HNQ, you'll get 10 UVs for linking to wiki and adding a picture of a glass of water showing nucleation points. That doesn't help anyone build a house....

Comment: @Mazura The data is provided as-is, and it is intended as an index with various ways to sort it, and not (by itself) as a source of statistical information, which it obviously cannot provide. (You could have found this out, if it was previously unclear to you, by politely asking what the data was meant to do, instead of blithely assuming otherwise and launching unwarranted attacks.)

Comment: As for "Why would that knowledge need to be kept hidden if the list was a good thing?", I have no idea why you think the mechanism for selecting questions for the list is secret. The algorithm is perfectly public and has been documented [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343) and [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/11602) for the past eleven years, with some *minor* tweaks documented [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/325060) as soon as they were implemented.

Comment: @KyleKanos People not downvoting enough **is** particular to HNQ, because many people who visit those questions because they see them in the hot bar cannot downvote them. In fact, I do put effort to get at least a bit of reputation on QAs that I visit in HNQ for this very reason, to be able to downvote bad content that reaches HNQ.

Comment: @TomášZato I recognize the disparity in abilities for upvotes vs downvotes on 101 rep users, but I think that even regular users downvote too infrequently.