# Can I ask about these shoes from Dr.Stone?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

I'm watching Dr.Stone (an anime/manga) and have noticed the rather odd shoe design used by a people of a village (shown below). Can I ask about how those shoes would be of benefit to the environment in Dr.Stone? (Things like area, friction, hardness, stone-and-ground interaction, etc)

[image: Stone shoes (colored)]

[image: Stone shoes (black and white)]

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10911/44126).

Comment: This isn't exactly science fiction. The manga/anime is made to be quite scientifically realistic. I'd like to know if the design is any good in their environment and in the real world.

Comment: This is NOT about fictional science. The story is fictional but based on real life physics. My question is about analyzing how the shoe design would work in real life and in the story. It's a relatively simple design and can be made in real life. I'm just curious who that design would actually work out.

Comment: Benefit to the environment? I'm not sure that's a physics question. I'd also wager that any answer to such a question about the character designs would be more art related than physics related.

Comment: What I'm wondering is whether or not that design, considering things like material, area on the bottom, balance, etc. would be effective or beneficial given the environment they're in. It's kinda like discussing the physics of high-heels and how it can be used on tiled floor but not dirt roads.

Comment: "Why are high heels designed the way they are?" would not be on-topic either, for a number of reasons. Primarily because it isn't a physics question, but a question about the mixture of engineering and art that goes into making shoes.

Comment: Your question has additional problems. Most notably that it requires in-depth knowledge of the fictional universe you're asking about more than it requires knowledge of physics. At a glance, this seems like it could be on-topic on the [Anime & Manga SE](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), so you might think about asking it there.

Comment: I don't need the readers to know about the universe of topic. I just want to discuss the practical aspect of the design really. There's not much besides that since the design is set in a Stone Age environment where fashion doesn't apply much. I'm really just wondering if the design would create more problems or benefits. I'd imagine the thinned out base would be troublesome with less surface area and a higher center of gravity. There may be more, which is what I'm curious about.

Comment: *where fashion doesn't apply much* no one said anything about fashion. It's more about the art design of the animation and character development teams than anything.

Comment: I'd like to just ignore everything about the setting and just focus on the functionality of the design. Is it OK to ask about *just* the practicality of the design considering the physics?